# Regex to allow a limited number of UTF characters i.e. allows only 2, 25 utf8 characters

Tags: php, regex

I need a php regular expression that should allow all characters of all languages with a limit of minimum 2 chars and maximum 25 chars. Below is the code that I am trying.

```
$post = 'Sıhhiye-Ankara àl škofja loka is a long string ';
preg_match('/[\p{L}]{2,25}/u', $post);
```

The Regular expression allowing utf chars correctly but the limit of 2,28 is not working.

Comment: Assuming you only allow 2-25 code points, what is your definition of `all characters of all languages`? Is it supposed to allow punctuation like `-` in your example? What about combining marks, numeric digits?

Comment: I want to allow users to input string which could be minimum 2 characters and maximum 24 characters long. What I meant by "all characters of all languages" is that I want to accept utf-8 characters. Punctuation marks and numbers are also allowed. Sorry if my question is confusing. Thanks!

Comment: `/^.{2,25}$/su` matches all characters in Unicode, including control characters.

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh -  /^.{2,25}$/su  - this worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anchors `^` and `$`, they will make sure matching starts at the beginning and ends at the end of the string:

```
preg_match('/^\p{L}{2,25}$/u', $post);
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL5fX9/2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use anchors. Anchors helps to do an exact match. `^` matches start of a line and `$` matches end of a line boundary.

```
preg_match('/^\p{L}{2,25}$/u', $post);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{M}]{2,25}$/u', $post);
```

Add `^$` anchors and use `\p{M}` too if you want to match a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).